# Change size of tableview if array used for 'numberOfRowsIndexPath' .count is 0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

As of right now the row still shows up but it its empty leaving a blank row.  I'm trying to change the size of the tableview so the row is removed completely.  Currently the cell style is grouped.  Here is the code so far:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = peopleImagesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: imagesCellIdentifier) as! ImagesPeopleCell

      cell.imageDelegate = self
      cell.extraPhotosArray = self.personalImagesArray
      cell.profileImagesArray = self.extraImagesArray

      if self.personalImagesArray.count > 0 {
        self.peopleImagesTableView.rowHeight = 150

      } else {
        self.peopleImagesTableView.rowHeight = 0
        self.peopleImagesTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 582, width: 335, height: 210)//This doesn't appear to be doing anything
        self.peopleImagesTableView.reloadData()
      }

          return cell

}
```

Comment: Never call reloadData from within `cellForRowAt`. Never change anything about the table view in `cellForRowAt`. Bad, bad, bad. Only configure and return one cell. That's all you must ever do in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: you should use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to change cell height at `indexPath`.  And you current code is setting the cell height to 0, if `personalImagesArray` is empty.

Comment: @f_qi Why? If there are no rows in the table, then there are no rows to set the height for.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change size of table view. In viewDidLoad() add this line :

tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

Comment: and also remove if else part from cellForRowAt.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide tableview  when 'numberOfRowsIndexPath' .count returns 0 rather than changing frame.